# django get an empty queryset by some query

Tags: django

In some cases, I want to get an empty queryset by something like:

```
from django.db.models import Q

query = Q()
query &= Q(...)

if some_condition:
    query &= Q(something_i_want)  # here

X.objects.filter(query) # get an empty queryset if some_condition is True
```

How can I do this?

a possible solution I can do with is:

```
if some_condition:
    query &= Q(pk=0)
    query &= Q(pk=1)
```

but this looks ugly :(

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for either a queryset result, or an empty queryset if some condition is met. Correct?

Comment: yes, if some_condition is met, i want the filter result to an empty result with that 'query'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the none queryset, there is a `none()` type.

```
if some_condition_met:
    query = MyModel.objects.none()
```

Documentation on [`none`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#none)

> Calling none() will create a queryset that never returns any objects and no query will be executed when accessing the results. A qs.none() queryset is an instance of EmptyQuerySet

This behaves like a queryset, except that it is empty.

So your code would look like this:

```
query = None
if some_condition:
    query = MyModel.objects.none() 
else:
    conditions = Q(..) | Q(..) #whatever your filter criteria are
    query = MyModel.objects.filter(conditions)

#Here, you have empty queryset if the condition is met
```